# текст выходит за границы колонки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, найти и исправить ошибку. Только начинаю осваивать верстку бутстрап. Почему-то текст не распределяется внутри столбца, хотя внутренние границы есть.

```
<div class=row>
 <div class=col-md-8><h1>sdfkgjsdlfkhdf</h1>
  <p>skjhfksjdhfksjhdfksjhdfksjdhfksjhdfkjshdfkjsdhfksjdhfksjdhfksjdhfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
 sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
 <div class=col-md-4>sdfgsdfgfdg</div>
```

css:

```
 .col-md-8{border:1px solid orange; padding:8px;}
 .col-md-4{border:1px solid orange; }
```

Comment: выложите ваш код, чтобы понять что не правильно

Comment: Вы написали слишком длинное слово, браузер не знет как его переносить, поэтому оно вышло за границы элемента

Comment: у вас просто не правильно была написана разметка

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ht5zfcbo/ вот работающий ваш пример

Comment: @Crantisz Спасибо! Теперь все в порядке!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

> Свойство word-wrap указывает, переносить или нет длинные слова,
>   которые не помещаются по ширине в заданную область. Данное свойство
>   носит черновой характер и при валидации документа на CSS3 выдает
>   ошибку.

[источник](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

Пример:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;  
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    Lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
  </div>
```

Ваш пример:

```css
 .col-md-8{border:1px solid orange; padding:8px; word-wrap: break-word;}
 .col-md-4{border:1px solid orange; word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class=row>
   <div class=col-md-8>
     <h1>sdfkgjsdlfkhdf</h1>
    <p>skjhfksjdhfksjhdfksjhdfksjdhfksjhdfkjshdfkjsdhfksjdhfksjdhfksjdhfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
      sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf </p>
   </div>
    
   <div class=col-md-4>sdfgsdfgfdg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S: У Вас в структуре html ошибки (не закрытый параграф).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я вроде читала, что его не обязательно закрывать, или это все-таки нужно?

Comment: @Алина, "Если закрывающего тега нет, считается, что конец абзаца совпадает с началом следующего блочного элемента."  Лучше закрывать, чтобы избежать ошибок.